# Do you get an extra turn when you promote your pawn?

Tags: rules, pawn-promotion

If you promote a pawn do you get a second move to move it out of danger? Or do you still only get the promotion as your move and it becomes the opponents move?

Comment: cool idea, but no it doesn't work like that

Answer (score 17):

> Once you have promoted your pawn do you get a second move to move it out
>   of danger?

No.

> Or do you still only get the promotion as your move and it becomes
>   the opponents move?

Yes.

From the FIDE Laws of Chess:

> 3.7.e When a player, having the move, plays a pawn to the rank furthest from
>   its starting position, he must exchange that pawn as part of the same
>   move for a new queen, rook, bishop or knight of the same colour on the
>   intended square of arrival.

There is no discussion of extra turns.

Answer (score 4):

NO. You move the pawn to the eighth rank, promote it to a piece, and then your turn ends.

What confuses some people is that the "promotion" is a second action, which *feels* like a second turn. So they wrongly remember getting a second "turn."